# Tomcat hangs on shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, spring-data-solr

We started to use spring-data-solr within our project for some admin use-cases that we need to implement.

### Setup

Our setup for spring-data-solr  is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:solr="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr.xsd">

   <solr:repositories base-package="com.any.package" solr-template-ref="solrTemplate"/>

   <solr:solr-server id="solrServer" url="http://${solr.host}:${solr.port}${solr.contextPath}" />

   <bean id="solrTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate">
          <constructor-arg ref="solrServer" />
          <constructor-arg value="${solr.storeCore.name}" />
   </bean>
```

Currently we are using one `Repository` which extends the `SolrCrudRepository` and which is autowired to a `Controller`.

### Problem

When shutdown Tomcat, it hangs for 10 minutes on `Destroying the ProtocolHandler`.

A Threaddump does not provide much more information, except that a `searcherExecutor`-Thread is parked.

Any Ideas?

### Versions

- Solr: 4.7.2
- Spring-Data-Solr: 1.5.4.RELEASE
- Spring: 4.2.5.RELEASE
- Tomcat 7.0.53
- Java 1.8.0u65
- Win 7 and CentOS 6.6

Comment: Everything fine with spring-data-solr... as expected ;-) There was a solr component, which did not close the core after usage.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment: Everything fine with spring-data-solr... as expected ;-) There was a solr component, which did not close the core after usage.